# Find the nearest set in multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, euclidean-distance

I have 3 numpy arrays, i.e. `x`,`y`,`z`, which each have equal length. Also, matching indices between the 3 numpy arrays form a single set, e.g. `(x[i],y[i],z[i])`. Given `x`,`y`,`z` as known arrays and an arbitrary target set, e.g. `a = [0.0,1.0,2.0]`, is there an efficient numpy-thonic way to compute the index, `i`, that finds the closest single set in `x`,`y`,`z` to `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of `numpy` vectorization,

```
import numpy as np

all_indices = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,3))
target = np.array([1.3,4.5,10])

dist = np.linalg.norm(all_indices-target,axis=1)
closest_ind = np.argmin(dist)
```

---

**UPDATE**

The solution above can be generalized to multiple targets like this

```
import numpy as np

all_indices = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,3))

all_indices = all_indices[:,None,:]
target = np.array([[1.3,4.5,10],[1.3,15,8],[20,6,10],[1.3,15,8]])
dist = np.linalg.norm(all_indices-target,axis=2).T
closest_ind = np.argmin(dist,axis=1)
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot. Is there an efficient way to generalize it, i.e. compute closest distance and closest index for each target, if there are multiple targets, e.g. `target = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[-1.,10.,1.]])`?

Comment: @Mathews24: There is even a more general method: the K-nearest neighbors for each array in `target` in the original `x`, `y`, `z` arrays and probably you are asking for 1-nearest neighbor.

Comment: @swag2198 That sounds about right, and simplicity and efficiency in code is sought for interfacing with numpy arrays.

Comment: Probably you want this:  `dist = np.linalg.norm(all_indices - target[:, None, :], axis=2)` and then `inds = np.argmin(dist, axis = 1)` where `target` can have any no. of elements.

Comment: In the case with multiple targets, is there a terse way to output only the minimum distance for each target? (The dimensions of `inds` and `dist` are no longer matching when multiple target are present.)

Comment: @Mathews24: To get the min. distances, use `np.amin(dist, axis = 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using the basic Python solution is 'un-numpy-thonic' in this case:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 2])
y = np.array([4, 4, 5, 6, 5])
z = np.array([7, 8, 8, 9, 8])

a = (2, 5, 8)

first_match = next(n for n, t in enumerate(zip(x, y, z)) if t == a)
all_matches = [n for n, t in enumerate(zip(x, y, z)) if t == a]
print(first_match, all_matches)
```

Result:

```
2 [2, 4]
```